# delete_if returning undefined method `include?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Not sure why this is happening, I'm just using the method how I see it here: [delete_if](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/delete_if)

But obviously I'm doing something wrong, just can't tell what.

This is my code:

```
non_enabled_speeds = ["Expedited", "Standard"]

parsed_rates = [{:service_name=>"Expedited",
  :service_code=>"XYZ", :total_price=>800, :currency=>"USD"}, 
  {:service_name=>"Priority", :service_code=>"PYT", 
:total_price=>1300, :currency=>"USD"},
  {:service_name=>"Standard", :service_code=>"XYZ", 
:total_price=>500, :currency=>"USD"}]

non_enabled_speeds.each do |non_enabled_rate|
  parsed_rates.delete_if 
{|rate| rate[:speed].include?(non_enabled_rate)}
end
```

I understand that `delete_if` uses `include?` under the covers, but I'm not sure why I'm getting this error:

```
undefined method `include?' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: your rates don't have value for `:speed`

Comment: good lord.. need more coffee.. thanks

Comment: Ruby is an object oriented language, not an Arrays-of-Hashes-of-Strings oriented language. I suspect you would find this much easier to code and debug if you defined some classes to handle this data - e.g. `Rate`.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, it's not about `delete_if`. One (or more) of your `rate[:speed]`s is `nil`.

```
{|rate| rate.fetch(:speed, []).include?(non_enabled_rate)}
```

Comment: More like ALL of them :)

Comment: Oops, I did not check the array :D

Comment: arghhhhh.. sorry for the post.. not enough coffee!!